# Lambda Range For Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, lambda

**Note:** I am not sure if I should ask this question here or at CodeGolf, so I am going to post it here in case it is appropriate.

I am trying to make a for loop in python using lambdas that follows this format:

```
x = 10
y = range(10)
w = 2

for g in range(w*w, x, w):
    y[g] = 0

print y
```

This outputs the correct list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9]`. However, I cannot get the list to change by using lambdas. My code is this:

```
print(lambda w,x=10,y=range(10): (map(lambda g: (lambda f=y.__setitem__: (f(g,0) )()), range(w*w,x,w)), y))(2)

"""
w is the step value in the for loop, which is 2
x is the size of the list, 10
y is the list, range(10)

lambda g is the first argument for map as the function. It sets the value of the list y at the current index g to be 0, through the use of lambda f's setitem
range(w*w,x,w) is the second argument passed to map as an iterable. In theory, all the indexes of y in this list should be set to 0 through the use of lambda f

y is returned to be printed
2 is the value passed to w
"""
```

However, this returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` which is wrong. Does anyone know how I can achieve this in one line? Should I use other builtins to make the loop in lambda? I used [this](http://caisbalderas.com/blog/iterating-with-python-lambdas/) and [this](http://p-nand-q.com/python/lambda.html) for reference in case it helps.

Comment: Is the aim to make it one line?  Or to use lambdas to eliminate all for-loop type constructs?  Can list comprehensions be used?

Comment: Its supposed to be a one line prime sieve. This is just a part of it.

Comment: You shouldn't do things like this. This is very bad code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easier to use list comprehensions:

```
print (lambda w, x=10, y=range(10):\
       [(0 if (i >= w*w and i < x and i%w==0) else n) for i, n in enumerate(y)])(2)
```

Moved to two lines for readability, but you can delete the \ and the line break and it will run fine.

One caveat is that this doesn't alter the original list, but returns a new one.

If you needed it to update the original list AND return it, you could use short-circuiting:

```
print (lambda w, x=10, y=range(10):\
       ([y.__setitem__(i, 0) for i in range(w*w, x, w)] and y))(2)
```

Correction:

The code above works only if `range(w*w, x, w)` is non-empty, i.e. `w*w > x`, which is a weak condition.

The following corrects for this issue:

```
print (lambda w, x=10, y=range(10):\
       (([y.__setitem__(i, 0) for i in range(w*w, x, w)] or 1) and y))(2)
```

This uses the fact that `(a or 1) and b` always evaluates to `b` after the value of `a` gets evaluated.

Comment: Generally `(expression1 and expression2)` in Python evaluates to `expression2` if `expression1` is Truthy (e.g. a non-zero number, non-empty list etc), and `expression1` if `expression1` is Falsy (0, [] etc).

Answer (score 1):

It's an abomination to use `map` for it's sideeffects, but:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = range(10)
>>> w = 2
>>> map(lambda i: y.__setitem__(i, 0), range(w*w, x, w))
[None, None, None]
>>> y
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9]
```

A less objectionable approach is to use slice assignment

```
>>> y = range(10)
>>> y[w*w: x: w] = [0]*len(range(w*w, x, w))
>>> y
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9]
```

Comment: In your first example, how would I get y returned by printing the lambda?

Comment: You mean like `print (lambda:(map(lambda i: y.__setitem__(i, 0), range(w*w, x, w)), y)[1])()`?

Comment: You can do the print with the sideeffect like this `print (map(lambda i: y.__setitem__(i, 0), range(w*w, x, w)), y)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure `lambda` implementation, which takes `w`, `x`, and `y` as arguments to a top-level `lambda`:

```
>>> (lambda w,x,y: (lambda s: map(lambda v: 0 if v in s else v, y))(set(range(w*w,x,w))))(2,10,range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9]
>>>
```

Note that this avoids the use of `__setitem__`.